# Using standalone document option displaying minted code on a single line

Tags: minted, standalone

I want to use standalone option for my latex document. I am trying to display code using the minted package but the entire line of code gets displayed on a single line. Below is a example.

code.cpp

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

sample latex document

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\inputminted{verilog}{code.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `standalone` options you need to add option `varwidth`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % here I add your file with code.cmp
    \begin{filecontents}{code.cpp}
int main(){
return 0;
}
    \end{filecontents}

\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % now it is part of LaTeX
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{float}  % have no sense in standalone

\begin{document}

\inputminted{verilog}{code.cpp} 

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]